# Garbled output from gradle when redirecting stderr to stdout. Jenkins gradle plugin suffers

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, output

When all output from gradle is redirected like

```
gradle clean build > buildlog 2>&1
```

java compiler warnings output like

```
...
:build
:application:compileJava/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/some/path/somefile.java:87: warning: somewarningtext
1 warning

:application:processResources
```

Note that there are no spaces nor linefeeds between `application:compileJava` and the warning text. It would be ok but we use Jenkins gradle plugin and it outputs executed gradle task names in a box that is meant to be narrow.

But it contains     :application:compileJava/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/some/path/somefile.java:87: warning: somewarningtext instead of just `:application:compileJava` and causes build log to display in a weird way:

[image: weird jenkins build log display]

Do I have some workarounds to apply in that case? I want build log to be readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One workaround might be to add a linebreak by your own for all tasks of type compile:

```
allprojects{
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
        doFirst{println "\n"}
    }
}
```